# When do covering and packing have the same behavior: when does $\log N_p(\delta) \lesssim \log N_c(\delta)$ for all $\delta > 0$ hold?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, packing-and-covering

Let $X \equiv (X, d)$ denote a compact metric space and let $N_c(\delta), N_p(\delta)$ denote the covering and packing numbers of space, respectively. Here $\delta > 0$.

Evidently we always have $N_c(\delta) \leq N_p(\delta)$: a maximal $\delta$-packing is a $\delta$-covering.

My question is when a logarithmic converse holds. That is, for which spaces does there exist a finite constant $C_X \geq 1$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ we have
$$
\log N_p(\delta) \leq C_X \, \log N_c(\delta). 
$$